# Listing Folders in a Directory using asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, directory, getfiles

.aspx file:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Explorer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

.CS file:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.IO;

public partial class view2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "~/";
    GetFilesFromDirectory(path);
}

private static void GetFilesFromDirectory(string DirPath)
{
         try
         {
             DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirPath);
             FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
             foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(FI.FullName);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
}
```

I want to list the folders in a particular directory but it continuously showing blank page.Can anybody tell what's the problem in the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Display directories and files on a blank page

```
// YourPage.aspx
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<html>
<body>
    <% foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo("E:\\TEMP").GetDirectories()) { %>
        Directory: <%= dir.Name %><br />

        <% foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles()) { %>
            <%= file.Name %><br />
        <% } %>
        <br />
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im trying to do something similar but i dont want to use a static path. Is there a way to get the application path? for example "~/Uploads/" and Uploads is a folder inside of my web project. I dont want to have this: "C://Visual Studio 2013/ projects/my project" etc

Comment: @Ra3IDeN yes, use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(StringPathInSolution)` , however as the path to your project is static and thus known you could remove it from the string?

Comment: it does not fetch files in my case

Comment: Correct! You are Pro!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Console.WriteLine()` use `Response.Write()`. You're trying to write to the console in a web application.

Comment: I'm getting this error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Response.get'

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: Oh, remove `static` from `private static void GetFilesFromDirectory(string DirPath)`. You don't need it in this case.

Comment: Thank you It removed the error .But my web page is still showing nothing.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: Are you sure no errors are being thrown? Did you replace both instances of `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: yes I replaced all instances and I still get nothing.Getting the page same as earlier.

Comment: Try putting a break-point (assuming you're running from an IDE) in the `GetFilesFromDirectory` method and see if you can step into it (F11 while execution is paused at the break-point).

Comment: In my oppinion Response.Write doesn't work at Page_Load/Pre_Init and such events. The Response will cleard bevor rendering aspx.

Comment: I couldn't understand it.But can you help me in just displaying folders(not subfolders) in the way benjamin told.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: If this didn't work for you, and Benjamin's did, you should award the answer to him, not to me. I'm sure he'd be able to help you with his code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine will write to the console, not the web page contents you are returning.  You need to add a container element to your ASPX page, probably a grid view or repeater, then add assign the file list from the code behind file (to the HTML element you added, use the runat='server' tag and assign it an ID, then reference it by ID name in the code).

Answer (score 1):

Response.Write in a static codebehind method: DIRTY! In addition you did't control the position where you write. This a little bit cleaner...

```
// YourPage.aspx
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <% foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) { %>
        <li><%= file %></li>       
        <% } %>     
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have your `<li>` and `<ul> mixed up. Also, I do agree with you but the user seems to just be doing something basic right now (the page is blank and there's nothing else in the code-behind) so I didn't really see the point of getting into perfecting the display. Also, I didn't even notice that the method was `static`, good eyes. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.I'm very new to coding.

Comment: Please tell me this.I just want to display folders in a directory(not subfolders).In your code replacing Files with Directories giving every folder in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Directory class

- The first parameter is the path it can be relative or absolute
- The second parameter for matching against the names of subdirectories in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal and wildcard characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions.

/

```
//using System.IO; 
private void GetDirectories()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("direction",typeof(string));
    try
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"yourpath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dir);
        }
        if (dirs.Length <= 0)
        {
             lbl.text="your message"

        }

       rpt.DataSource = dt; //your repeater 
       rpt.DataBind(); //your repeater 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       lbl.text="your message"//print message assign it to label
    }
}
```

In the aspx page

```
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("direction")%></td>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```