# How to give resolution for looking server folders?

Tags: asp.net, iis

In my web application users need to chose folder with special file. But they don't see paths on server. How can I open server folders for viewing?
On local machine i look all directories fine:
[image: local viewing in web application]

On server like this:
[image: server viewving in web application]

Comment: mate you need to provide more context other wise others will give you only vote down not an answer
I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047228/listing-folders-in-a-directory-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for the detail I also see you changed the title that's good for the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the TreeADirectory with a valid server path and you will have you tree rendered :)

```
private void TreeADirectory(TreeView treeView, string pathToList)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathToList);
    var node = CreateDirNodes(rootInfo);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
}

private static TreeNode CreateDirNodes(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    var dirs = directoryInfo.GetDirectories()
    foreach (var directory in dirs)
    {
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    }
    //only if you need to show files
    var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles()
    foreach (var file in files )
    {
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    }
    return directoryNode;
```

}

Comment: Thanks but i need another answer. I did directories opening. But directories aren't been showed on my web client when i connect to server

Comment: You need to show you code then :) how can I guess
Please  provide your code otherwise no body can help you