# Display local drive/files in browser with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-office

How can I display a shared drive/folder in the browser? This is for a company intranet. Ideally, I'd like users to be able to click a file (ppt, excel, word) and have it open in office.

I've done something similar by embedding a sharepoint site in an iframe but I don't need the entire site, just the folder containing the files.

I don't want to manually enter the file paths because this folder may be updated and the new files should display automatically.

I'm using C# but an example in any language will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm not sure where to start. I've seen this done before just don't know how.

Comment: After a quick search, list files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047228/listing-folders-in-a-directory-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp
access a shared folder with user/password: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232120/c-how-to-logon-to-a-share-when-using-directoryinfo

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8881/Web-File-Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.IO` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should have all that you need.

```
var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\10.0.0.1\myFolder\test\")
```

To display it in ASP.NET, check out [Listing Folders in a Directory using asp.net and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047228/listing-folders-in-a-directory-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

This is done by using WebDav, which is a network protcol. It's implemented in sharepoint but it's not depending on sharepoint, but if i remember correctly, the dll that's used is called Sharepoint.ddl.
I have no real experience using Webdav but there some frameworks to help you out.
Maby  http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/ is something that fit your needs.

Heres a link to a webdav that a colleague tried and liked http://www.webdavsystem.com/server
Note that Webdav also opens up the support for "live" saving and editing files, so you don't have to reupload the file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Quick code in ASP.NET based on [Listing Folders in a Directory using asp.net and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047826/2224861).

Doesn't handle user permissions.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<% foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Path\To\Share").GetFiles())
{ %>
    <a href="<%= file.FullName %>"><%= file.Name %></a>
    <br />
<% } %>
```