# Read Drive files inside sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I want to read files from server drive inside share point page using page viewer web part, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an ASP or .NET page that runs on the server that runs the code and point your page viewer web part to that. This page will likely be something you have to set up through the IIS on the server rather than through SharePoint. Here's a [Stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047228/) about someone who did that with ASP & C#.